# php first and last weekday (workable Mon-Fri) of month using simple strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime, weekday

**Solved! i leave it here for you.**

This two lines of code are ok for the first workable day:

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime('+0 weekdays October 2016'))
```

Returns :  3-10-2016       --> OK

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime('weekday february 2016'))
```

Returns :  1-2-2016        --> OK

The last workable day of a given month and year:

```
$year=2016;
$month='october';
$lastworkable=date('d-m-Y', strtotime('last weekday '.date("F Y", strtotime('next month '.$month.' '.$year))));
```

Returns :  29-07-2016  for july    --> OK

Comment: if i understand right ? so u need last of the month right?

Comment: Yes, given a month and year i need the last weekday, example october 2016 would be 31. July 2016 would be 25. Thanks

Comment: Why weekday? do `date('d-m-Y',strtotime('last day of october 2016'));`

Comment: Isn't the last weekday in July 2016 the 29th? Maybe we mean something different by "weekday".

Comment: Sorry.. yes July 2016 i need to get the 29th, not 25.

Comment: just edited the original question to be more specific, i need the workable day

Answer (score 4):

I hope this one will help you

**Edit 1**

```
  <?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime("last Monday of July 2016")); //25-07-2016
   echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime("last Monday of October 2016")); //31-10-2016
```

**Edit 2**

Sure this will help you

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-09-01 first weekday'));
```

Comment: Ahhh, `weekday` means `first day of the last week of the given month` now i got it :))) fine answer

Comment: `last weekday of october` points out that monday is needed? really?

Comment: And just to make angry :) `php first and last weekday of month using simple strtotime` isnt ansered fully ;)

Comment: Sorry "I'm Back"... i dont need the last monday, i need the last workable day (Mon-Fri)... but "last weekday of October 2016" doents works, it gives me an error and "last weekday October 2016" gives me 30 Septembrer. Your code will not work in april.

Comment: Just edited the original question to be more specific with a couple of examples, i need the workable day

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, i solved the problem and updated the original question with the answer, that code will give the first and last workable day of a given month and year.

Answer (score 0):

And if you dont want to use strtotime, maybe to avoid the 2038 Bug (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) you can use the following code.

(new DateTime('first day of next month'))->modify('last weekday') will give you the last weekday of the actual month.